# Parsing JSON fails as strings appear instead of dicts/lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

```
with open('twit/example.json', encoding='utf8') as json_data:
    for line in json_data:
        try:
            dataText = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError:
            continue

for a in dataText:
    print(a["user"]["location"])
```

the result is: **string indices must be integers**

Update: The below answer is for printing

```
print(dataText["user"]["location"])
```

now I want this one:

```
print(a["user"]["location"])
```

Comment: What does the json file look like?

Comment: it is json file from API's twitter and I want to print the location of each tweets in the file.

Comment: See my answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your json file is in a normal format, use this instead:

```
with open('twit/example.json', encoding='utf8') as json_data:
    dataText = json.loads(line)

for a in dataText:
    print(dataText["user"]["location"])
```

The way your code is currently written makes me think you have multiple json structures in a single file, separated by new lines. This is not how json is usually formatted.

Comment: it said File "<ipython-input-27-5da4ecf31ae7>", line 5
    for a in dataText:
                      ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Comment: edited the code, try again but remove the `try:` and the 4 spaces before

Comment: it worked, thank you for your help,,

Comment: what if I want to print(a["user"]["location"])

Comment: `user` is a part of `dataText`, but you can still do `a["location"]` for each `user`s in `dataText` (if you have more than one `user`)

Comment: I wrote: `for a in dataText["user"]:
    print(a["location"])` but dosn't work