# Getting users location in twitter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Json file that contains tweets from Twitter' API. Now I want to get the users location that they put in their profile. I wrote this code:

```
with open('twit/example.json', encoding='utf8') as json_data:
for line in json_data:
    try:
        dataText = json.loads(line)
    except ValueError:
        continue
for a in dataText:
   print(a["user"]["location"])
```

the result is: **string indices must be integers**

How I can solve it?

Comment: You posted the same question [an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44579796/8160345) and I gave you [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44579858/8160345). You are still using your old code even after you said my answer helped. Please don't duplicate questions.

Comment: no it is another question, see the last line.

Comment: @adifalla "How I can solve it?"   "How I can solve the problem?" apart from this everthing is same. You kidding ?

Comment: @Vimal I edited my post in my old one. Now I want to print "a" instead of "dataText".